# When does int++ get incremented?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've got a line of code,

```
list[index++] = recursiveFunction();
```

Does `index` get incremented before or after the call to `recursiveFunction`?

Comment: It probably depends on the implementation.

Comment: You're telling me there's no standard?

Comment: @Rafe Kettler, in C# I doubt that. The specs are pretty clear on most things.

Comment: @jball but we don't know which version of Visual Studio he's using, or if he's using Mono, etc. You're probably right though @Ralph there's different versions of Visual Studio (VS2008, VS2005, etc.), as well as Mono.

Comment: I'll tag this as VS2010 because that's what I'm using, but it's not so useful if it'll run differently on someone else's machine. Found a better way to do what I was trying to do anyway.

Comment: Don't know, but it's more readable for anyone reading the code if index++ would be in another line. Plus, it is implementation agnostic.

Comment: @user: The reason I wanted it on one line is because I wanted `list` to receive 1 index, and the function to use the next index... but I really did not think that through at all. Even though it *does* do what I wanted it to do, it's still not what I needed it to do :p I need a 2nd variable to save the old value anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The increment operation is executed **before** the function call. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691322(v=VS.71).aspx. Note that this is not relevant to the precedence and associativity of operators.

> The order of evaluation of operators in an expression is determined by the precedence and associativity of the operators (Section 7.2.1).
>
> Operands in an expression are **evaluated from left to right**. For example, in `F(i) + G(i++) * H(i)`, method F is called using the old value of i, then method G is called with the old value of i, and, finally, method H is called with the new value of i. This is separate from and unrelated to operator precedence.

Operator precedence and associativity only affect the way operators are bound to operands. The question here talks about *side effects* of the evaluation of operands.

```
using System;

class Obj {
   public bool Incremented {get;set;}
   public static Obj operator ++ (Obj o) {
     Console.WriteLine("Increment operator is executed.");
     return new Obj {Incremented = true};
   }
}

class L {
  public int this[Obj o] {
    set { Console.WriteLine("Assignment called with " + 
            (o.Incremented ? "incremented" : "original") + " indexer value."); }
  }

}
class Test{
  static void Main() {
    Obj o = new Obj();
    L l = new L();
    l[o++] = Func();
  }

  static int Func() {
    Console.WriteLine("Function call.");
    return 10;
  }
}
```

Prints:

```
Increment operator is executed.
Function call.
Assignment called with original indexer value.
```

This behavior is *clearly specified* in the specification and should be identical in any conforming compiler.

Answer (score 5):

Under Visual Studio 2008/.NET Framework 3.5 on Windows, index is incremented **before** `recursiveFunction` is called.  This sample app prints "index = 1" to the console.

```
class Program
{
    private int index = 0;

    private static void Main()
    {
        new Program().TryMe();
    }

    private void TryMe()
    {
        var list = new List<int>();
        list.Add(1);
        list.Add(2);

        list[index++] = ReturnZero();
    }

    private int ReturnZero()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("index = {0}", index));
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ralph - Glad we could be of help!